# Execute a thread after the end of method?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix, sleep

I have a following scenario,

```
void* Refresh(void *)
{
 usleep(10);
 ..
}

static void RefreshViews()
{    ...
     pthread_t t;
     pthread_create( &t, NULL, &Refresh, NULL);
     ...
}
```

I want to run a thread at the end of RefreshViews() function. For it to work(temp solution) properly, I have added sleep in another thread at the beginning of its execution in Refresh() function.

How can I handle this situation better?

Comment: Create the thread just before leaving the function?

Comment: So, you want the other thread to start after a short delay?

Comment: Why doesn't it work properly?

Comment: Not clear to me what you actually want

Comment: I just want another thread to execute after RefreshViews() has finished executing and control goes back to its caller.

Comment: It works properly, it seems sleep is not necessary. But without sleep I might crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three methods you can use:

1. Like I said in my comment, start the thread just before you leave the function.

   ```
   static void RefreshViews()
   {
       /* The code... */

       pthread_t t;
       pthread_create( &t, NULL, &Refresh, NULL);
   }
   ```
2. Create the thread in the function calling `RefreshViews`.
3. Have an extra function, that acts as a proxy to the real function, and which creates the thread:

   ```
   static void RefreshViews()
   {
       RealRefreshViews();
       pthread_t t;
       pthread_create( &t, NULL, &Refresh, NULL);
   }
   ```

One thing about the first method, is that you have to remember to create the thread if you have an explicit `return` before the end of the function. Or use `goto` to go to the thread creation instead of `return`.

Answer (score 0):

Define the thraed handle outsite of the static function or make the t static as well. The thread handle in your function will be destroyed as soon as you leave the function and t is poped from the stack. If you don't need any control over the thread (or remove it in a clean way) leave it, as it is.